# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'distinct'

Tags: sql-server, django, django-queryset, django-modeladmin

I have the below table view

```
CREATE VIEW vStaff
AS
SELECT ContactInfo .*, Staff.position
FROM ContactInfo 
LEFT JOIN Staff ON Staff.name = ContactInfo.name
```

that selects information from these two models

```
class ContactInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

However, when I try to select from the `vStaff` like below in `modelAdmin` I get the above error

```
Staff.objects.annotate(val=RawSQL("SELECT * FROM vStaff", ()))
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'distinct'

Comment: I'm not familiar with `RawSQL`, but are you sure you don't need a "FROM" in your query? As an aside you should never `SELECT *` inside a view because it won't automatically update if you change the table definition.

Comment: From is there in `RawSQL`

Comment: Alright the View itself is fine, as it is able to select required information but the problem is in django `modelAdmin` where I am getting the error

Comment: why you have `select * vstaff` instead of `select * from vstaff` Now I see this is my typo sorry for that

Comment: But I am getting the same error anyway.

Comment: Can you use the debugger or the stack trace to locate the exact line that's giving the error? It is obviously not in any of the code you've posted because there is no reference to an attribute _distinct_.

Comment: `select * from vStaff` returns neither ContactInfo nor Staff records. Have you tried creating a class with the correct properties? Also I'm not sure how smart Django's parser is, i.e.: you may need to specify `"select name, email, address, position from vStaff"` instead.